# Query variable arrays

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I use an array variable as a query argument instead of the literal array itself?

For example, the documentation mentions the following:

```
var result = db.query({name: db.anyOf(['fred', 'barney', 'mark']});
```

But instead, I wish to do this:

```
var myTeam = ["fred","barney","mark"];
var result = db.query({name: db.anyOf(myTeam)});
```

So far, I have not been successful.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Your code works fine for me (besides the missing parenthesis typo).

```js
function scriptdbTest() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  db.save({name:'fred', age:40}); //just to get one result on my test script

  var myTeam = ["fred","barney","mark"];
  var result = db.query({name: db.anyOf(myTeam)});
  while( result.hasNext() )
    Logger.log(result.next().toJson());
}
```